# RESTful Actions Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I've got a RESTful User model working well in Rails 3. I'd like to add a new option to create a new user based on information queried out of a LDAP server.

What I'd like advice on is how best to do this. Here's what I've thought up so far, but I don't know if it matches Rails best practices:

Edit the resource path of User to accept both GET and POST to a new view called "import_ldap_user".

Import LDAP user then presents a form which uses AJAX (POSTing to import_ldap_user) to allow the visitor to search for a person in LDAP. The results are displayed on the page and if acceptable, the user clicks "Create", which then calls /user/create.

Part of why this seems bad to me is:

1. I need to post a proper @user to /user/create, but I'm not sure if my AJAX call can produce a proper @user.
2. I don't know if it's a bad practice to add a new verb to the RESTful Users route.
3. I don't know if using an AJAX POST to import_ldap_users is a proper separation of concerns.

Any ideas? Any Rails perfectionists have opinions about how this should work?

Answer (score 2):

What gets posted to /user/create isn't an @user object but rather its attributes. A scaffolded create action will probably have something akin to `@user.new(params[:user])`, which just pulls the user attributes that were posted and creates a new object based on that.

Even if your AJAX call doesn't provide the attributes in a manner that can be processed by the `new` method, you can simply modify your `create` such that it manipulates the post data.

As for best practices, this is definitely something I've thought about in the past but I don't know if there's a "correct" answer. I think having a new view which posts to the `create` method is perfectly acceptable, you could also create a new controller if you want to strictly follow the CRUD pattern.

Definitely a good question and if anyone has a better answer I'd love to hear it.